# same code but different output in my phone on uc browser google & chrome browser

Tags: android, html, css, browser, responsive

I tried to center the Header text ('Beyond Mountain ') .  but in my phone it did not work in UC browser. it's only works chrome browser on my phone.Not working in uc brower.

html-
          `<div class="content">
                <h1>Beyond Mountain !</h1>
                <a class="btn" href="form.html">Get Started</a>
            </div>`

CSS:

```css
.content{
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center;
 } 

   .content h1{
       font-family: Raleway, sans-serif; 
       color: #F9F3F4; 
       font-size:450px;
    }
```

[image: screenshot]
This problem occurs only in UC browser

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: sorry, I am new this site i tried to upload the code..the post is not submitted that's why..          this my  css code -

Comment: .content{
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.content h1{
 font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
 color: #F9F3F4;
 font-size:450px;}

Comment: Could u post ur website link ?

Comment: and `font-size: 450px;` is too big :p

Comment: this not any web site . it just a  sample webpage. it's perfectly working in pc/laptop . but in my adroid phone i faced this problem on UC browser